# How do I refer to getter funtions in Vue with the same name?

Tags: vue.js

```
  ...mapGetters('player', ['messages']),
    ...mapGetters('coach', ['messages']),
```

If I have two getters with the same name. How would I access them? this.messages doesn't work because there are two.

Answer (score 2):

You can use alias. you must supply the namespace to the mapGetters helper in each line

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({ pMessage: 'player/messages'}),
    ...mapGetters({ cMessages: 'coach/messages'}),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using vuex namespace:

The first parameter of mapGetters can be a namespace:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters("fooModule", [
        "barGetter"
    ]),
    ...mapGetters("anotherModule", [
        "someGetter"
    ])
}
```

That will make the value available as `this.barGetter` or just `barGetter` in templates. Note, it's perfectly acceptable to have multiple mapGetters statements.

This should work in your needs:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('player', ['messages']),
    ...mapGetters('coach', ['messages']),
    }
```